# is firebase data base realtime does delete Id it's self if user not active for several days?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

i have these 3 `methods`

one listening to internet status

```
listenToInternet() {
      FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child(currentUser.uid!).onDisconnect().set({
        "activity": DateTime.now()
      });
  }
```

and one for manual get online when user open the app

```
   getOnlineInResumedOrAtTheStartRun(){
        FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child(currentUser.uid!).set({
          'activity': "online",
        });
      }
```

and one for manual get offline when user close the app

```
getOfflineInInactive(){
    FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child(currentUser.uid!).set({
      'activity':  DateTime.now(),
    });
  }
```

ok now everything going fine as well ..

but i noticed if user didn't open his account on the app for 4-5 days so his Id `.child(currentUser.uid!)` disappear from data base without any order from user  , and if he open the app again so his `.child(currentUser.uid!)`show again in `data base`

note : i also noticed there is strange id get instead that one who disappeared !

Is there something I missed or does it happen normal in data base ? or i should chick my code again ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, No, it doesn't delete users on its own. I have multiple applications that are not active more than two years from now and the users are still there. Make sure you are authenticating the users and then saving those in your Database.

In addition to this, define security rules from the console so as to keep your data secure.

Comment: "Make sure you are authenticating the users and then saving those in your Database." can you please explain more about it or what do you exactly ? .. if i am not wrong any .set() should be there as mush as there no order to delete it by code